# Can I get the stacktrace for a console.error() in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-proptypes

I'm running some `jest` tests (`react` component testing using `enzyme`). One particular file has 100+ tests. All of them are passing, but I'm getting 3 `console.error()` messages from a library that I'm using, specifically the `prop-types` library used with `react`. The error isn't specific enough that I can know which test is causing it.

Is there any way that I can have `jest` output the stacktrace at the time of the error so that i can know exactly which component is causing the issue?

The error, for what it's worth, is of the form:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `data` is marked as required in `StateOverview`, but its value is `undefined`.
          in StateOverview
```

The problem is that I have dozens of instances of `StateOverview`, and many of them are not passing in that particular prop. It seems weird that I would have solely one error message despite this happening **many** times. Or is that the expected behaviour? Any insight would be appreciated!